# Concatenating selected rows and outputting to new column

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create a macro that concatenates the values in the rows I select (can vary between 2 rows to 5 rows) and outputs the concatenated results into a new column.

So far, the concatenation and the creating of the new column works. However, the concatenated results also output to a couple of the other columns that have information I need in them, replacing the data that’s there.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```vb
Sub ConcatenateSelectedColumns()
   Dim SelectedRange As Range
   Dim NewColumn As Range
   Dim Cell As Range
   Dim ConcatenatedValue As String

   ' Set the range of selected columns
   Set SelectedRange = Selection

   ' Insert a new column to the right of the selected range
   SelectedRange.Columns(SelectedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert

   ' Set the header for the new column
   SelectedRange.Offset(, SelectedRange.Columns.Count).Value = "New Column"

   ' Loop through each row in the selected range
   For Each Cell In SelectedRange.Rows
       ConcatenatedValue = ""
       For Each SubCell In Cell.Cells
           ConcatenatedValue = ConcatenatedValue & SubCell.Value
       Next SubCell
       Cell.Offset(0, SelectedRange.Columns.Count).Value = ConcatenatedValue
   Next Cell
End Sub
```

PROCESS:

- setting variables
- make space for a new column + insert one into the table as well as rename it.
- starting a loop for each row in the selected range of columns.
- resetting the “concatenatedvalue” variable into an empty string at the start of each new row.
- append the value of each cell in the row to ConcatenatedValue to concatenate them together.
- putting concatenated values into the new column for the current row.

I believe the issue is with the last step, just not sure how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have posted the revised code.  `Selection` validation w/ `TypeName` is necessary and tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ConcatenateSelectedColumns()
    Dim ColIndex As Long
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ConcatenatedValue As String
    ' Check if a range is selected
    If Not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the columns you want to concatenate.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Add a new column to the right of the selected columns
    With Selection
        ColIndex = .Cells(1).Offset(0, .Columns.Count).Column
        Columns(ColIndex).Insert
        Cells(1, ColIndex).Value = "NewColumn"
        ' Loop through selected cells
        For Each rngRow In .Rows
            ' Stop at the blank row if whole column(s) are selected
            If Application.CountA(rngRow) = 0 Then Exit For
            ConcatenatedValue = ""
            For Each Cell In rngRow.Cells
                ' Concatenate values from selected columns
                ConcatenatedValue = ConcatenatedValue & Cell.Value
            Next Cell
            Cells(rngRow.Row, ColIndex) = ConcatenatedValue
        Next rngRow
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]